# Replace all instances of a character in an object

Tags: jquery, replace

I have cloned a selector, but before I output it, I wish to replace all instances of `data_number` with `data_number + 1`, but I'm having trouble.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
var data_number = $('.data-fields').length, // The number of data rows
    data_row = $('.data-'+data_number),  // The last data row
    new_data_row = data_row.clone();        // A clone of the last data row

/** Replace all instances of the data_number with data_number + 1 */
???

/** Clear all of the input values in the clone */
$('input[type="text"]', new_data_row).val('');

/** Output the now clean cloned data row */
data_row.after(new_data_row);
```

For example, if new_data_row was originally -

```
<div class="data-5">
    <input name="data[5][label]" />
    <input name="data[5][budget]" />
</div>
```

I wish it changed to -

```
<div class="data-6">
    <input name="data[6][label]" />
    <input name="data[6][budget]" />
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `replaceText` function declared?

Comment: I was using a function I got on this site, but I've just noticed that would only work for text anyway, not things like the classes (which is what I need to change). I've amended the question to take that part out, and better reflect what I am asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty. DOM --> html --> replace --> DOM.

```
var data_number = $('.data-fields').length, // The number of data rows
    data_row = $('.data-'+data_number),  // The last data row
    cloned_data = data_row.clone(),
    new_data_row,       // Raw html
    next_number = data_number + 1; 

cloned_data.find("input").val(""); //Clear inputs

new_data_row = cloned_data.wrap("<div/>").parent().html().replace(new RegExp(data_number + "", "gm"), next_number + "");

/** Output the now clean cloned data row */
data_row.after(new_data_row);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm getting an error though - `ReferenceError: Reqexp is not defined`. Also, when setting `new_data_row = data_row.html()`, will this not mean that the top level container is lost?

Comment: Misprint: Reqexp --> Regexp :). 
Corrected to copy top level container.

Comment: Ok, got it running with no errors (`RegExp`), but it doesn't seem to be working. Alos, if I were to do it this way, I'd lose the ability to clear all of the `<input>` values.

Comment: Added: input clear and saved replacement result. This should work as expected.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks for you time, this is now working as I would like. I did make one small adjustment to the line for clearing inputs - instead of `.val()` I had to use `.attr('value', '')` as it was just not clearing the values down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using [string replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) and your `data_number + 1` needs to be `parseInt(data_number) + 1` unless you want to literally append 1 to the end of your string.

Comment: Good point on the use of `parseInt()`, but I'm not sure how I treat `new_data_row` as a string?

Comment: That depends on what new_data_row is originally.  Is it a dom element <tr>?  <td>?  You may need to go with innerHTML or it might be a .val()

Comment: @J.T.Blum: Why `parseInt`? $().length is always a number.

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko: You know, I hadn't even noticed that.

Comment: @J.T.Blum - `new_data_row` is a DOM element. Thanks.

Comment: `$(new_data_row).children('input').each(function(i) {
this.name.replace('data['+data_number,'data['+data_number+1);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer here was longer than I'd hoped.

Also, this only works because I am manually replacing all the elements that I know need replacing, so if there are any better methods, please do share.

**Update**

I've accepted another answer because it achieves exactly what I want, so although this code will work, I'd recommend that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var link = $('.add-data-link');     

    link.on('click', function(){

        var data_number = $('.data-fields').length, // The number of data rows
            next_number = data_number + 1,          // The next data number
            data_row = $('.data-'+data_number),     // The last data row
            new_data_row = data_row.clone(),        // A clone of the last data row
            class_name = 'data-'+data_number,       // The class of the cloned data
            new_class_name = 'data-'+next_number;   // The new class that will replace the cloned data

        /** Replace all instances of the 'data_number' with 'next_number' */
        var for_text, name_text;
        $(new_data_row).removeClass(class_name).addClass(new_class_name);
        $('label', new_data_row).each(function(){

            for_text = $(this).attr('for');
            for_text = for_text.replace(data_number, next_number);
            $(this).attr('for', for_text);

        });
        $('input', new_data_row).each(function(){

            name_text = $(this).attr('name');
            name_text = name_text.replace(data_number, next_number);
            $(this).attr('name', name_text);

        });

        /** Clear all of the input values in the clone */
        $('input[type="text"]', new_data_row).attr('value', '');

        /** Output the now clean cloned data row */
        data_row.after(new_data_row);

    });

});
```